# AlwaysOn Availability Groups back up schedules

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

We have AlwaysOn Availability Groups primary and secondary replicas where the secondary replica is preferred for back up jobs to take place as long as it is available. I created back up jobs on both replicas and scheduled the jobs at the secondary replica.

My question is: - Do I have to schedule the jobs at the primary replica and then disable them until fail-over occurs and then manually enable jobs, or what is the best way to deal with these please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is: - Do i have to schedule the jobs at primary replica and then disable them until fail-over occurs and then manually enable jobs or what is the best way to deal with these please?

No, you should just add a check with the new function `sys.fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica`

```
if sys.fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica('your db name') <> 1
begin
    print 'This is not preferred backup replica .....'
        -- If this is not the preferred replica, exit (without error).
end
else
begin
    print 'This is the preferred replica .. continue with backup'
        -- If this is the preferred replica, continue to do the backup.
        -- here goes the backup command .....
end
```

Alternatively, you can use **[SQL Server Maintenance Solution - by Ola hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/)** which supports AlwaysON as well.

Comment: So, if I use Ola's solution on both replicas and schedule the jobs, I don't have to add "sys.fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica" function since Ola's solution script has it already - correct ?

Comment: @Jared yes it has it. [High Availability --> Does the SQL Server Maintenance Solution support AlwaysOn Availability Groups?](https://ola.hallengren.com/frequently-asked-questions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Below steps are used if you are using  https://ola.hallengren.com/ ,  SQL Server Maintenance Solution - by Ola hallengren which supports AlwaysON as well.

I recommend that you configure it like this:

1. Have the jobs enabled and scheduled on both servers.
2. Add @CopyOnly = 'Y' to the full backup jobs.
3. Drop the differential backup jobs

Ola's jobs will then automatically perform the backup on the preferred replica.

Comment: Do u need to put this parameter ? @AvailabilityGroups = 'ALL_AVAILABILITY_GROUPS, ALL_DATABASES'